# Get stack output without deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, next.js, aws-cdk

I have a project that uses AWS NextJS and Lambda@edge on the frontend, with an AWS Cognito UserPool managing authentication.

Since Lambda@Edge does not support environment variables, I'm having to bake the userpool id into the NextJS code at build time. To do that, I've had to do the following

1. Create one stack containing just the userpool
2. Create another stack containing the rest of the application (including Lambda@edge)
3. Deploy stack 1. first, get the UserPool ID as an output. Deployed with `cdk` and `--outputs-file` so I get the outputs as a JSON file
4. Parse the outputs file and use it to bake the UserPool id into the NextJS build, using the `env` key in the config
5. Deploy stack 2 containing the NextJS application

This seems to work, but its quite a slow process because

- Stack 2 depends directly on stack 1 for other reasons using CDK public fields on the stack
- This means that step 4 above also ends up redeploying stack 1 - so I actually have to deploy stack 1 *twice*

Can anyone think of a better solution to the above problem that doesn't end up deploying the userpool stack twice? Is it possible to get the UserPool ID from a stack containing a Cognito UserPool without doing a full deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to perform a stack2 only deployment by running the `cdk deploy` command with the `--exclusively`  flag. e.g. `cdk deploy --exclusively stack2`:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6215

Otherwise, if you store your UserPool ID into SSM parameter store and then pull resolve it as part of your 2nd stack deployment (either via CDK or as part of your NextJS code build) then you should be able to get the 2 stacks to deploy independently of each other.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html

```
const ssmParameter = new ssm.StringParameter(this, 'mySsmParameter', {
   parameterName: 'mySsmParameter',
   stringValue: MyUserPool.id,
   type: ssm.ParameterType.STRING,
});
```